# A problem - Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Sticks have mean mass 60g with standard deviation 15g, and the distribution of their masses may be taken to be normal. Sticks of less than 45g are classed as ‘light’. The remainder are classed as either ‘standard’ or ‘heavy’ and it is desired that these two classifications should occur with approximately equal frequency. Suggest the mass at which the division between standard and heavy should be made.

How to tackle this problem? Please

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Step 1: Find $P(m < 45)$.

Step 2: Suppose that you classify an object as standard if it is between $45$ and $m_s$ and as heavy if it is greater than $m_s$.

What should $P(45 < m < m_s)$ and $P(m > m_s)$ equal?